# Getting the db name or url used from models in php activerecord?

Tags: php, database, phpactiverecord

How can I get the database name or url used in my models in [php activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org)?

I have

```
$connections = array(
   'conn1' => 'mysql://user:pass1@localhost/db1;charset=utf8',
   'conn2' => 'mysql://user:pass2@localhost/db2;charset=utf8',
   'conn3' => 'mysql://user:pass3@localhost/db3;charset=utf8'
 );
```

I need to know what database are using my models, so I want to get from some object method the strings `conn1` or `mysql://user:pass1@localhost/db1;charset=utf8`

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: @dnagirl I need get the url string from some object method like `Model::table()->connection->name;` but this not work.

Comment: so are you asking how to do something like `Model::table->connection->url`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way:

`ActiveRecord\Config::instance()->get_default_connection_string()`